# Laravel explode() url query

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

In my database is store a query input as BLOB which looks like this:
    make=ACURA&model%5B0%5D=MDX&model%5B1%5D=NSX&auction%5B0%5D=BAYAUC&auction%5B1%5D=IAA+Osaka

Now in my view, I try to get it and explode:

```
@foreach(explode('=', $url) as $par)
     {{ $par }} 
@endforeach
```

But I get an error:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

The end result I want to output like this:
ACURA MDX NSX BAYAUC IAA+Osaka

Comment: This looks more like a url query. You'd want [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) and [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Comment: Why not read the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) for information about what explode() does, and what arguments it takes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this php method for url query strign parsing : `parse_str($string, $output_array);`

#### PHP

```
$str = 'make=ACURA&model%5B0%5D=MDX&model%5B1%5D=NSX&auction%5B0%5D=BAYAUC&auction%5B1%5D=IAA+Osaka';
parse_str($str, $output);

// var_dump($output);
```

#### See Output : https://3v4l.org/LLvAV

#### Laravel Blade Example :

```
@foreach( $output as $opt )
    @if( is_array($opt) )
        {{ join(" ", $opt)." " }}
    @else
        {{ $opt." " }}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you're trying to do but you used `explode()` function the wrong way.

The right way is `array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit = PHP_INT_MAX ] )`

> The 3rd parameter is `limit` and `MUST BE AN INTEGER` which mean If limit is set and positive,
>   the returned array will contain a maximum of limit elements with the
>   last element containing the rest of string.
>
> If the limit parameter is negative, all components except the last
>   -limit are returned.
>
> If the limit parameter is zero, then this is treated as 1.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Sorry, I just trying output all the parameters of the string. In the end, it will user favorite search request.